# new android activity not starting

Tags: android-intent

hello guys I an trying to switch to a new activity from my main activity but I am getting `'the application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again'`. I am not sure why.

here is my current activity:

```
public class EditActivity extends ListActivity {
    TextView selection;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListContent));  
    }
    private static String[] mListContent={"Fishing Reports", "Choose a Fishing Spot", "Prediction","Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3","Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3","Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                 case 0 :     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed item 1 !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                 case 1 :     
                              Intent myIntent = new Intent(EditActivity.this,  LocationActivity.class);
                              startActivity(myIntent);
                             break;
    }

      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
```

here is the activity I an calling

```
public class LocationActivity extends ListActivity {
    //Your member variable declaration here

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location);  
    }   
}
```

The new activity is declared in my manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".LocationActivity"></activity>
```

here is the layout of my new activity:

the current activity works fine but when I click on second item on `mListContent (case 1)` , it does not launch the second activity, I get the error `'the application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again'` any ideas why?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Alright, thanks guys,
I found my problem. The new activity that I was trying to call was extending ListActivity. so I changed it so it extends Activity, that seemed to have fixed the problem,
Again thanks to this forum !! But you know how this goes it won't be long before I bump into another problem ... it's life haha

Answer (score 0):

When you use a ListActivity, you need to make sure that your layout has a ListView with an id of "@android:id/list" so the ListActivity can find it. If you don't, it will force close on startup.

Something like this:

```java
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

BTW, if you're using Eclipse, here's a tip to help with debugging.

In the Eclipse menu, choose Window > Show View > Other..., expand the Android category, select LogCat, and click OK. This will open the LogCat view which captures all the log output from your emulator or device.

I like to set up a filter in LogCat so it's easier to find the app messages; click the little green plus symbol to create a new filter, and enter "AndroidRuntime" for the "Filter Name" and "by Log Tag" fields. This filter will show up as another tab on the LogCat view, you can filter the contents any time by switching to that tab.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem. what is the reason for this force close coming up. But I am using only activity and not list activity. Still I get the force close. Log cat does not help at all.